# C++ Memory Leak using g++ compiler

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm working on some homework for my C++ class but am stumped on this memory leak I'm getting.

I've been looking around but cannot find the source of the problem. What I also find weird, which may or may not be common, is that when I compile it in g++ the memory leak is at the end after the entire program has run.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Like I said I'm a beginner. Thank you for your help.

```
//--------------- MYSTRING.CPP ---------------
// The class definition for fractions.
//
// Michael Arciola

#include "mystring.h"
#include <typeinfo>


MyString::MyString() // -------------------------------------------------- // #1
{
    length = 0;
    data = new char[length + 1];
    data[0] = '\0';
}

MyString::MyString(const char* s1)
{
    length = strlen(s1);
    data = new char[length + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        data[i] = s1[i];
        //cout << s1[i];
        //cout << data[i];
    }

    data[length + 1] = '\0';
}

MyString::MyString(int s1)
{
    int temp;
    char c = 'm';
    MyString final;
    int count = 0;
    length = 0;
    data = new char[length + 1];
    int s2;
    s2 = s1;

    while (s1 != 0) 
    {
        temp = s1 % 10;
        s1 = s1 / 10;
        c = temp + '0';     
        count++;
    }

    length = count;

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        temp = s2 % 10;
        s2 = s2 / 10;
        data[i] = temp + '0';       
    }


    data[count] = '\0';

}

// Destructor   ----------------------------------------------------------- // #2
MyString::~MyString()
{
    delete [] data;
}

// Copy Constructor 
MyString::MyString(const MyString& s1)
{
    length = s1.length;
    data = new char[length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        data[i] = s1.data[i];
    }

    data[length + 1] = '\0';
}

// Assignment Operator
MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString& s1)
{
    if (this != &s1)
    {
        delete [] data;

        length = s1.length;
        data = new char[length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
            data[i] = s1.data[i];
        }

        data[length + 1] = '\0';
    }

    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const MyString& s1) // --------------- -// #3
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++)
    {
        os << s1.data[i];
    }

    return os;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& is, MyString& s1) 
{
    // NEED HELP

    /*
    is >> s1;

    return is;
    */
}

istream& getline (istream& is, MyString& s1, char delim)    
{
    // NEED HELP
} 

bool operator< (const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2)  // ------------- // #4
{
    if (strcmp(s1.data, s2.data) < 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator> (const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2)
{
    return s2 < s1;
}

bool operator<=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2) 
{
    return !(s2<s1);
}

bool operator>=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2)
{
    return !(s1<s2);
}

bool operator==(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2)
{
    return (s1<=s2) && (s1>=s2);
}

bool operator!=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2) 
{
    return !(s1==s2);
}  

MyString operator+ (const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2) // ------------ // #5
{
    MyString newstring;
    int len = s1.length + s2.length;

    newstring.grow(len);

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++)
    {
        newstring.data[i] = s1.data[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++)
    {
        newstring.data[s1.length + i] = s2.data[i];
    }


    return newstring;
}

MyString& MyString::operator+=(const MyString& s1) 
{
    int start = length;
    int growth = s1.length;
    int totallen = s1.length + length;

    grow(growth, start);

    cout << "Start: " << start << endl;
    cout << "Length: " << length << endl;

    for (int i = start; start < length; i++) 
    {
        cout << "data[i]: " << data[i] << endl;
        cout << "s1.data[i]: " << s1.data[i] << endl;
        data[i] = s1.data[i];
    }
}

char& MyString::operator[] (unsigned int index) // ------------------------ // #6
{
    return data[index];
}

const char& MyString::operator[] (unsigned int index) const
{
    return data[index];
}

int MyString::getLength() const // ------------------------------------------ // #7
{
    return length;
}

const char* MyString::getCString() const
{
    return data; 
}

MyString MyString::substring(unsigned int start) const // ------------------------- // #8
{
    MyString temp;

    for (int i = start; i < length; i++) 
    {
        temp.data[i] = data[i];
        cout << temp.data[i];
    }

    return temp;
}

MyString MyString::substring(unsigned int start, unsigned int size) const
{
    MyString temp;

    if (size + start > length) {
        size = length;
    } else {
        size += start;
    }

    for (int i = start; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if (i != size)
        {
            temp.data[i] = data[i];
            cout << temp.data[i];
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

MyString& MyString::insert(unsigned int index, const MyString& s) // ---------- // #9
{
    if (index > length) {
        index = length;
    }

    grow(s.length, index);
    int len = s.length;
    int ph = 0;

        for (int i = index; i < index + len; i++) {
            data[i] = s.data[ph];
            ph += 1;
        }
}

int MyString::indexOf(const MyString& s) const // ------------------------------// #10
{
    int final;

    if (strstr(data, s.data) == 0) {
        final = -1;
    } else {
        final = strstr(data, s.data) - data;
    }

    return final;
}

void MyString::grow(int len) {

    char* temp = new char[length + len + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }

    /* FOR TESTING
    for (int i = length; i < length + len; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = 'm';
    }
    */

    temp[length + len + 1] = '\0';

    data = temp;
    length = length + len + 1;
}

void MyString::grow(int len, int index) {

    char* temp = new char[length + len + 1];
    int ph = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) 
    {
        temp[i] = data[i];
        ph += 1;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < index + len; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = ' ';
    }

    for (int i = index + len; i < length + len + 1; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = data[ph];
        ph += 1;
    }

    temp[length + len + 1] = '\0';

    data = temp;
    length = length + len + 1;
}

void MyString::reverse() {

    char temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++) { // Loops through array, add value to temp, and move it to the other side of the array
        temp = data[i]; 
        data[i] = data[length - i -1];
        data[length - i -1] = temp;
        cout << data[i] << endl;

    }

}
```

This is the error I'm receiving.

```
*** glibc detected *** a.out: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000001323d0a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3b0de714af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x3b0de757ab]
a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x38b)[0x400d1b]
a.out[0x402208]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x3b0de1d9f4]
a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x49)[0x4009d9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 00:1e 30277703                           /home/majors/arciola/COP3330/assignment5/a.out
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 00:1e 30277703                           /home/majors/arciola/COP3330/assignment5/a.out
1323d000-1325e000 rw-p 1323d000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3b0da00000-3b0da1c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10128338                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3b0dc1c000-3b0dc1d000 r--p 0001c000 08:02 10128338                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3b0dc1d000-3b0dc1e000 rw-p 0001d000 08:02 10128338                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3b0de00000-3b0df4f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10128359                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3b0df4f000-3b0e14f000 ---p 0014f000 08:02 10128359                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3b0e14f000-3b0e153000 r--p 0014f000 08:02 10128359                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3b0e153000-3b0e154000 rw-p 00153000 08:02 10128359                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3b0e154000-3b0e159000 rw-p 3b0e154000 00:00 0 
3b0e200000-3b0e282000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10128554                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3b0e282000-3b0e481000 ---p 00082000 08:02 10128554                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3b0e481000-3b0e482000 r--p 00081000 08:02 10128554                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3b0e482000-3b0e483000 rw-p 00082000 08:02 10128554                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b79d5f7d000-2b79d5f80000 rw-p 2b79d5f7d000 00:00 0 
2b79d5fb1000-2b79d609c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3852142                    /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
2b79d609c000-2b79d629c000 ---p 000eb000 08:05 3852142                    /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
2b79d629c000-2b79d62a3000 r--p 000eb000 08:05 3852142                    /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
2b79d62a3000-2b79d62a5000 rw-p 000f2000 08:05 3852142                    /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
2b79d62a5000-2b79d62b8000 rw-p 2b79d62a5000 00:00 0 
2b79d62b8000-2b79d62ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3852164                    /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
2b79d62ce000-2b79d64cd000 ---p 00016000 08:05 3852164                    /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
2b79d64cd000-2b79d64ce000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 3852164                    /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
2b79d64ce000-2b79d64d0000 rw-p 2b79d64ce000 00:00 0 
7fff51c4e000-7fff51c63000 rw-p 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                      [stack]
7fff51dfd000-7fff51e00000 r-xp 7fff51dfd000 00:00 0                      [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Abort
```

Comment: Are you asking **if** you have a memory leak?  Or do you know you have one, but you don't know where?  Or do you know where it is, but you don't know why?  Or do you know why, but you don't know how to fix it?  It's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: I think in your `const char*` constructor `data[length + 1] = '\0';` should be `data[length] = '\0';` Also your `int s` constructor sets `length = 0;` before allocating the buffer using `length`.... perhaps you should allocate after calculating `count`?

Comment: where is the `main` function? You posted too much code and also not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grow() method allocates a new array, and replaces `data` with the array, without `delete`[]ing the previous contents of `data`. That's your leak.

In addition, I also see non-portable, undefined behavior in your assignment operator. Comparing pointers to two objects is undefined behavior, unless the objects belong to the same array or vector.

Comment: Thanks you for reply! I believe I made the changes but I'm still getting this error after the program is finished.

Comment: Comparing pointers to different objects is *unspecified* in C++ (all versions). It's UB in C.  Stronger guarantees than just *unspecified* were added by C++11 so that `std::map<T*, U>` is viable .

Comment: "This error" is memory corruption. Use valgrind to instrument your code, and identify memory access violation. If you never used valgrind before, this is an excellent opportunity to learn how to use it.